# junit test with Eclipse

Tags: testing, junit

Hi i am trying to use junit and it does not work s well.

Here is my code.

```
package safe;


import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import safe.SafetyException;

public class SafetyInspector {

public static boolean isSafe(Class<?> clazz) throws SafetyException{


    if (clazz.equals(Object.class)) return true;
    if (clazz == null ) {
        throw new SafetyException();
    }

    Field fields[] = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field f: fields){
        f.setAccessible(true);
        int mod = f.getModifiers();
        if (Modifier.isFinal(mod)){
            continue;
        }
        else if (Modifier.isPrivate(mod)){
            Class<?> typeArray[] = new Class<?>[1] ;
            typeArray[0] = f.getType();
            try {
                Method mSet = clazz.getMethod("set" + f.getName().substring(0, 0).toUpperCase() + f.getName().substring(1),typeArray );
                int modMet = mSet.getModifiers();
                if(!Modifier.isPublic(modMet)) return false;
                if(!mSet.getReturnType().equals(void.class)) return false;
            } 
            catch (SecurityException e) {

                throw new SafetyException();

            } 
            catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

                return false;
            }

            try {
                Class<?> typeArray2[] = new Class<?>[1] ;
                Method mGet = clazz.getMethod("get" + f.getName().substring(0, 0).toUpperCase() + f.getName().substring(1),typeArray2);
                int modMet2 = mGet.getModifiers();
                if(!Modifier.isPublic(modMet2)) return false;

                if(!mGet.getReturnType().equals(f.getType())) return false;
            } 
            catch (SecurityException e) {

                throw new SafetyException() ;
            }
            catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

                return false;
            }





        }



    }


    return isSafe(clazz.getSuperclass());

}

public static void sort(List<Class<?>> classes) throws SafetyException{ 

    for (int i = 1; i < classes.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < classes.size() - i; j++) {
            if (compare(classes.get(j), classes.get(j + 1)) > 0) {
                swap(classes, j);
            }
        }
    }       

}

public static void reset(Object object) throws SafetyException{

        Class c = object.getClass();
        Field fields[] = c.getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field f :fields ){
            if (!isSafe(f.getClass()))
            {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                try{
                    if(!f.getClass().isPrimitive()){

                    }
                    else if(f.getClass().equals(boolean.class)){
                        f.setBoolean(object, false);

                    }
                    else{
                        f.set(object, 0);
                    }
                }

                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    throw new SafetyException();
                }


            }
        }



}




private static int compare(Class<?> o1, Class<?> o2) throws SafetyException {

        Field[] fields1 = o1.getDeclaredFields();
        int count1 = 0; 
        for (Field f : fields1){
            if (isSafe(f.getClass())) count1++;

        }
        Field[] fields2 = o2.getDeclaredFields();
        int count2 = 0; 
        for (Field f : fields2){
            if (isSafe(f.getClass())) count2++;

        }

        if (count1 == count2)
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());

        else return count1- count2;

    }

private static void swap(List<Class<?>> list, int j) {
    Class<?> temp = list.get(j);
    list.set(j, list.get(j+1));
    list.set(j + 1, temp);
}



};
```

and here is the code junit test that they gave me.

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;


import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

import safe.SafetyException;
import safe.SafetyInspector;


public class SafetyInspectorTest {
@Test
public void testIsSafeEmployee() throws SafetyException {
    assertEquals(false, SafetyInspector.isSafe(Employee.class));
}

@Test
public void testResetEmployee() throws SafetyException {
    Employee e = new Employee(123,3000);
    SafetyInspector.reset(e);
    assertEquals(0, e.id);
    assertEquals(3000, e.getSalary());
}

@Test
public void testSort() throws SafetyException {
    List<Class<?>> sortedClasses = new LinkedList<Class<?>>();
    sortedClasses.add(Employee.class);
    List<Class<?>> classes = new LinkedList<Class<?>>(sortedClasses);
    Collections.shuffle(classes);
    SafetyInspector.sort(classes);
    assertEquals(sortedClasses, classes);
}   
}
```

and when I run the safetyInspectorTest as a junitTESTCLASS i get an initialization error. I work with eclipse if it helps and I put Junit as a library of the project.

Comment: Sounds like a class path problem.

Comment: I add the junit.rar to the classpath

Comment: so it compiles but when i run it, it gets an initializtion error.

Comment: I hope you understand that "gets an initialization error" doesn't help at all. Paste the error in your question if you want help. Describe exactly how you're running it.

Comment: out of curiosity, where does the Employee class come from ? Is it possible that this class is missing from the classpath of the test running configuration ?

Comment: `I add the junit.rar to the classpath – user1088557` -- you should add jar files, not rar. Unless it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

An initialization error in JUnit is generally caused by a bad classpath.  See this related question which also suffered from initialization error:
[Eclipse JUnit - possible causes of seeing "initializationError" in Eclipse window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190699/eclipse-junit-possible-causes-of-seeing-initializationerror-in-eclipse-windo)

The most likely cause is as that question addressed, you are using a version of JUnit 4 which requires the hamcrest jar to be added.  Instead of adding the junit and hamcrest jars you should be able to add the JUnit 4 library on your project's Java Build Path.

Your imports largely look benign but you should confirm safe.SafetyException is on your classpath.

Finally, the initialization error could be caused by a static initialization failure in code that loads before your test runs.  The code you've posted looks safe but SafetyException class could possibly have an initialization block to check.