# Eclipse JUnit - possible causes of seeing "initializationError" in Eclipse window

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I know this question is pretty general but I haven't found any hints on why this error may show up. What are possible causes of seeing *initalizationError* in Eclipse window? I get no useful information just a long and useless failure trace (not included here).

I am using JUnit 4.11

I have written the following code - just to see if it works:

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SimpleTest {

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void test() {
    assertEquals(15, 15);
}

}
```

**Edit:** Sorry In Eclipse window it's called actually a "Failure trace":

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing     at
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)   at
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)   at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)   at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)   at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)     at
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)     at
org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at
org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at 
org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at
org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at
org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown
Source)     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)    at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)   at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)     at
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)     ... 25 more
```

Comment: include the stacktrace please?

Comment: Indeed - just because the stack trace (and full message) doesn't seem useful to you doesn't mean it's *actually* not useful.

Comment: You're missing some jar from your classpath. Check this out: [resource](http://java.dzone.com/articles/whats-junit-and-hamcrest)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You've probably got one of two problems:

1) You're using JUnit 4.11, which doesn't include hamcrest. Add the hamcrest 1.3 library to your classpath.

2) You've got hamcrest 1.3 on your classpath, but you've got another version of either junit or hamcrest on your classpath.

For background, junit pre 4.11 included a cut down version of hamcrest 1.1. 4.11 removed these classes.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to add hamcrest. Thank you guys for the information.

Comment: Matthew, Project > Clean just worked for me. Can you please tell me what the reason could be ? Thank you. Chenqui.

Comment: Exactly I'ts working for Junit.4.10.jar. But giving error for junit.4.11.jar. I tried 4.10 alone. Not tried solution for 4.11.

Comment: With my java8 upgrade. I updated to junit 4.12. It had hamcrest as its transitive dependency and solved the issue.

Comment: Forgot to import the hamcrest 1.3, life safer

Answer (score 53):

For me it was a silly mistake. I inadvertently set the test as **private** instead of **public**:

```
@Test
private void thisTestWasCausingProblems() {
...
}
```

it should have been

```
@Test
public void thisTestIsOK() {
...
}
```

Comment: Forgetting to declare the method's scope will cause the same issue. Declaring a method as public fixed it for me.

Comment: Had the same problem with @Before method. Saved the day!

Comment: I accidentally forgot to mark the _class_ as public.

Comment: My problem was similar - @Before method as private - thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Just try "Project > Clean..." - seems to be THE solution to many problems in Eclipse!

Comment: I was surprised to see that this method worked for me. It actually did ! Btw, I have Junit 4.11 and hamcrest 1.3 in my Eclipse project.

Comment: I did this (also disabled 'Build Automatically' until build was complete, and now it works! This is "THE" solution. Kudos!

Answer (score 11):

For me it was a missing `static` keyword in one of the JUnit annotated methods, e.g.:

```
@AfterClass
public static void cleanUp() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I had opposite problem using `@Before` and `@After`, those functions can NOT be static!

Answer (score 6):

I received this error when the class was annotated with @Ignore and I tried to run a specific test via right clicking on it.  Removing the @Ignore fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I've experimented the exact same error. My problem was that the SetUp method I had created was declared as static.

If using eclipse, one could get a good description by clicking above the error and then checking the Failure trace window, just below... That's how I found the real problem!

Comment: Thanks Pablo, that's exactly what I needed to find my problem.

Comment: If you don't see anything in the failure trace window click on the button Filter Stack Trace on top right of the failure trace window.

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure you have all `@Before`-, `@After`- and whatever-JUnit-annotated methods declared as `public`. I had mine declared as `private` which caused the issue.

Comment: Also problem in my project - mistakenly made the method private instead of public

Answer (score 2):

This problem also occurs if you have a private Rule in you class:

```
@Rule
private TemporaryFolder folderRule;
```

Make it public.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was due to the "return type" of the test method. It should be "void"

Comment: Yeah this got me too... i was quickly setting up a test, and just put the `@Test` annotation on a function by mistake, and it threw this error!

Answer (score 1):

For me it was something to do with commons-logging. Since I was using

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

This resolved my issue

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: Once it was excel path issue and other time it was missing `@Test` annotation.

Comment: Well, sadly Excel isn't part of the setup, and the method is annotated.

Comment: Having a Test Class with no `@Test` at all caused the initialization error for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and the same message. I was able to get it fixed by importing to the Java Building Path the `hamcrest-all-1.3.jar` archive. I'm using a JUnit 4.12 version.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that my parent class had no `@Test` methodes. I used there only some utilities. When I declared it `abstract` it works.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that I missed out @Test annotation on the test method.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had the following import in my test case:

`import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`

The correct import is:

`import org.junit.Test;`

Don't just import any old Test type from junit, make sure you pick the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Just if this helps, I was using Junit5 but the @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) was pointing towards import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner, which was messing around with things and hence was giving the initialization error.
I fixed this and it worked.

Comment: You should explain how you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I haven't added the hamcrest-2.2 (formerly hamcrest-library-2.2) jar in my buildpath.
[image]

Make sure to include all dependency (and their dependency jars) jars with JUnit 4.13.2 to run your tests:

- junit-4.13.2
- hamcrest-core-2.2
- hamcrest-2.2 (earlier hamcrest-library-2.2)

Comment: Consider replacing the image with maven dependency code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue... I was using maven building tool with JUnit dependency scope as 'test' and my @Test method was in main module.

To resolve, I've:
1. Commented the scope tag of JUnit dependency in the pom.xml
2. Rebuilt the package
3. Made sure the Test class has only one constructor

The issue can be two-folded:
1. The JUnit dependency is limited to test scope and the @Test method is in main scope
2. The test class has more than one constructor

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution for me is the following.

I had only install the junit.jar file from the web, but this library related with the hacrest-core.jar
When I downloaded the hacrest-core.jar file and added it in my project everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was one of the methods had to be void, I had it as Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Junit 4.11 doesn't work with Spring Test framework.
Also this link [InitializationError When Use Spring + Junit](http://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2016/09/initializationerror-when-use-spring.html) explains how to debug junit initalizationError in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the xtend language (or some other JVM lang with type inference) and haven't explicitly defined the return type then it may be set to a non-void type because of the last expression, which will make JUnit fail.

Answer (score 0):

I got another failure trace, but for future visitors using their favorite search engine:

For me the problem was that eclipse somehow decided to execute only a single method in my test class (I couldn't figure out why, though).
Especially if you did not change anything in your setup, check your run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have changed project name in pom.xml so the new target directory was generated and junit was searching classes in old directory. You need to change directory for JUnit also in Eclipse

`Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source (Default output folder)`

And also check because some of source folders listed in the same window may have former directory name. You need to change them too.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I mistakenly added a parameter to the test method which caused initialization error.

Answer (score 0):

I had naively added junit-4.12.jar from poi.apache.org to my Build Path in Eclipse. I deleted it (Project, Properties, Java Build Path, Libraries, junit-4.12.jar, Remove) then in my test class allowed Eclipse to "Fix Project Setup" after pressing Ctrl-1. No more problems! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I was not pointing to the correct package where I kept my feature (cucumber) file(s). This was a case of ***wrong path specification***. See code snippet below:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        
    features = "src/test/features",
    glue = "stepDefinitions"
        
        )
```

### Below is the screenshot of the JUnit error: [image: Junit Runner Error]

Below is the Stack Trace in the console:

[image]

The final solution was I had to change the path to the correct package where my feature files were kept.

### See the corrected code snippet below:

```
package cucumberOptions;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        
    features = "src/test/java/features",
    glue = "stepDefinitions"
        
        )

public class TestRunner {

}
```