# Eclipse JUnit - “initializationError”

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I know this question has been asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190699/eclipse-junit-possible-causes-of-seeing-initializationerror-in-eclipse-windo) but in my case `NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runners/ParentRunner`seems to be the problem

I am using JUnit 4.10

I have written the following code just to check if it works:

Junit Test File

```
package com.org.airportParking;

    import cucumber.api.junit.*;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @Cucumber.Options(
            format = {"pretty", "html:/target/cucumber"},
            features = "src/test/resources"
            )
    public class CukesRunner {}
```

Feature File

```
Feature: Valet Parking
    As a traveler
    In order to determine where to park my car
    I want to know the cost of valet parking

Scenario: Calculate valet parking cost for half an hour
    When I park my car in Valet Parking lot for 30 minutes
    Then I will have to pay for $12
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Failure trace

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type [unknown] not present
    at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.generateException(TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:83)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.value(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runners/ParentRunner
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:432)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:413)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:342)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:283)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3271)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3219)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.IgnoredBuilder.runnerForClass(IgnoredBuilder.java:13)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runners.ParentRunner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 39 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you missing the junit dependency?

Comment: I can see `junit-dep-4.1.10.jar` file under Maven dependencies

Comment: Right, and ParentRunner class is included. I tried to use the given dependencies and test in a simple Maven project and had no problems to run the "goal" test.

Comment: I ran the above code on my windows machine and had no problems whatsoever. Do I need to reinstall java, I am not able to find what is causing this problem?

Comment: As you are receiving a ClassNotFoundException I would try to check the classpath, With maven you could use` mvn dependency:build-classpath`. Have you also tried to remove the junit-dep dependency? JUnit should be pulled in automatically by the cucumber-junit dependency

Comment: Got rid of `junit-dep` from `pom.xml` and when I ran ` mvn dependency:build-classpath` the build is successful. when `mvn test` is run, I get `cannot find symbol symbol:   class Options location: class cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber` error.

Comment: ok, i checked the `Options` symbol in two different cucumber-junit versions (1.1.2 and 1.2.2). In 1.1.2 it was a public static interface inside Cucumber class, so the annotation was/is Cucumber.Options. With 1.2.2 it is CucumberOptions. Could you test with cucumber-java8 (if JDK8 is used) and cucumber-junit in version 1.2.2?

Comment: It couldn't resolve `CucumberOptions` after making changes to the `pom.xml`. I changed `cucumber-junit` versions to 1.2.2.