# InitializationError in a JUnit Test Case

Tags: eclipse, junit

I use eclipse and I have written the following code:

```
package JUnitTestPackage;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;

import JUnit_Test.BankAccount;

public class BankAccountTest {

    @Test
    public void testDeposit() {
        BankAccount account = new BankAccount();
        account.deposit(1000);
        account.deposit(100);
        assertTrue("Test Deposit", 1100 == account.getBalance());
    }

    @Test
    @Ignore
    public void testWithdraw() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    @Ignore
    public void testGetBalance() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

So, I work with Eclipse and JUnit for the first time. So, the code was only to learn how JUnit works. But when I click on Run as -> JUnit Test Case, then I get the message `initializationError`. I double-clicked on that error, and I got the following message:

[image]

My Failure Trace looks like the following:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

From an earlier post ([Eclipse JUnit - possible causes of seeing "initializationError" in Eclipse window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190699/eclipse-junit-possible-causes-of-seeing-initializationerror-in-eclipse-windo)) , I follow some advices, but withot success. For example, I have tried the following steps:

```
1. I have added harmcrest to my library
2. Go to Project -> Clean
```

I hope someone can help me.

best regards,

Comment: The stacktrace definitely indicates that the proper Hamcrest libraries are not in your classpath. Which Hamcrest libraries did you add, and where?

Answer (score 0):

Open your Java Build Path on your project properties, "Add Library", and add the JUnit 4 library.  You shouldn't need to add any JUnit jars directly.